# Russian letters in Matlab command window

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm facing a rather nasty problem. In Matlab, the command `S = char(1044)` puts Russian letter д into variable S. However disp(S) returns blank symbols, though the content is actually correct:

```
>> S = char(1044);
>> disp(S)

>> disp(S-0)
      1044
```

How can I make Matlab show Russian letters in the command window?

Comment: I have managed to get Russian letters shown by changing the Windows Format to Russian. But this spoils the rest of the system-wide settings, so it's a workaround rather than a solution. Anything better?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure it will help, but check out this:

> 1. The custom font preferences for the Editor and Command windows in MATLAB must be set to monospaced, plain. Go to File->Preferences->Fonts->Custom. Select 'Editor' or 'Command Window' from the text box and change the font preferences.

Taken from: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-8V70TK/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-8V70TK

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not help in any way. I think it was set exactly like that. If I choose some other fonts, I can get a rectangle instead of a blank space or a right-arrow. But no Russian letter.

Comment: See my comment to the question: the Russian letters are printed, independent from font, if the system Format is set to Russian. But I'd like to keep it as is, English (UK).